# SQL - Return all characters at the end of a string after a "-" at the end

Tags: mysql, sql

For example 'ABC-12345-6789-10' I want to return "10" as these are all the characters after the last "-" dash.

I have tried this but I only get a zero at the end:

```
SUBSTRING('ABC-12345-6789-10',len('ABC-12345-6789-10'),LEN(CHARINDEX('-', 'ABC-12345-6789-10')))
```

Comment: are you sure this is mysql?  mysql does not have a LEN() function.  if you meant LENGTH, mixing LENGTH and SUBSTRING doesn't work well with non-ascii data; you should use CHAR_LENGTH instead

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support the functions:

- `SUBSTRING` - you want `SUBSTR` instead.
- `LEN` - you want `LENGTH` instead.
- `CHARINDEX` - you want `INSTR` instead.

You want:

```
SELECT value,
       SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '-', -1) + 1) AS last_term
FROM   (SELECT 'ABC-12345-6789-10' AS value FROM DUAL)
```

Which outputs:

| VALUE | LAST_TERM |
| --- | --- |
| ABC-12345-6789-10 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mn4urCLX)

Comment: Thank you. I actually made a mistake, this is mysql, was doing oracle sql earlier in the day.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL it is easier. there you have `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('ABC-12345-6789-10','-' ,-1)
```

| SUBSTRING_INDEX('ABC-12345-6789-10','-' ,-1) |
| --- |
| 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_fUe6dKP)